Construct transformations of random variables that are "more normal"
I am reading this page in the Encyclopedia of Mathematics about transformations of random variables.
I am puzzled about the Example 2:

Let $X_1,...,X_n,...$ be independent random variables, each having a uniform distribution on [−1,1], and put
$$Z_n=\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{\sqrt{n/3}}.$$
By the central limit theorem,
$$ \{Z_n<x\}−Φ(x)=O(1/n). $$
If one sets
$$ V_n=Z_n−\frac{1}{20n}(3Z_n−Z_n^3), $$
then
$$ \{V_n<x\}−Φ(x)=O(1/n^2). $$

How do they get the rates $O(1/n)$ and $O(1/n^2)$?
I find the following result in this page about the central limit theorem:

... This result, in a somewhat stronger form, asserts that
$$ F_n(x)−\Phi(x)= \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\frac{Q_1(x)}{\sqrt{n}}+\cdots+\frac{Q_{s-2}(x)}{n^{(s−2)/2}}
+o\left(\frac{1}{n^{(s−2)/2}}\right)\right), $$
uniformly in x. This asymptotic expansion serves as the basis for the construction of a broad class of transformations of random variables.

Is this useful for getting the rates?

Example 3 in this paper is exactly your example: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1104012

@JJJuuu from the look of the abstract, that paper Hepdray linked is using Cornish-Fisher expansions. I'm not able to access that English version of the paper at present but the earlier Russian version seems to rely on using those expansions repeatedly, so the associated transformations may be a good place to start.
